# How much the USB slows down my external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I got a brand new 3TB Seagate FreeAgent external disk.
But it is TERRIBLY slow! Slow as a dead rabbit. 
Is it because of the USB 2 connection it uses? (Unfortunately is has no SATA connector). It sucks.

I used [Disk Tools](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-file-generator/index.html) to measure the speed. Look how fast are my old drives compared to the brand new one!

> Drive D:   -   [freeagent 3tb]                     --------- THE NEW
>   ONE Free space: 2376.10GB 
>   OS buffer: disabled
>
> ```
>       Write speed: 20.4MB/sec
>       Read speed: 25.22MB/sec
> ```
>
> Drive E:   -   [Old]
>   Free space: 69.88GB 
>   OS buffer: disabled
>
> ```
>       Write speed: 67.5MB/sec
>       Read speed: 65.60MB/sec
> ```
>
> Drive C:   -   [toshiba-500gb] 
>   Free space: 146.45GB 
>   OS buffer: disabled
>
> ```
>       Write speed: 75.0MB/sec
>       Read speed: 81.29MB/sec
> ```

Is this normal?

Comment: As I searched for the benchmarks of this model and yes they are showing that this is slow HDD. You can also see my this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/409616/why-is-writing-to-my-external-hard-drive-slow-while-benchmarks-show-fast-writin/409680#409680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the Wikipedia [USB article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Signalling_.28USB_PHY.29):

> According to routine testing performed by CNet, write operations to typical Hi-Speed hard drives can sustain rates of 25–30 MB/s, while read operations are at 30–42 MB/s; this is 70% of the total available bus bandwidth. For USB 3.0, typical write speed is 70–90 MB/s, while read speed is 90–110 MB/s.

So it indeed sounds like the USB 2 connection is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

> USB 2.0: Released in April 2000. Added higher maximum bandwidth of 480 Mbit/s (60 MB/s)

[USB (2.0) on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#USB_2.0)

Remeber, this is the upper limit. There is a great chance that the protocol to communicate with the USB device controller slows the communication down or that the firmware on the controller is implemented cheaply.

This is probably not caused by USB 2.0 alone, but by the casing you put the drive into.